# Is it a sin to fantasize about future wife?

Tags: zina, wife, sexuality

Assalamu alaikum,
I had some porn and masturbation addiction in past and also relation with a girl (not physical). It appears that her family will never let her to marry me, so I no longer kept that relation. I have broke away from all of those sins now and Alhamdulillah I've been quiet successful in this regard up until now. Though I sometimes struggle with the masturbation part.

Now sometimes I think about my future wife, like how we will lead our life, how we will have fun and also about how we will become intimate. In current circumstances of my family it's not possible for me to marry anyone before 6-7 more years, so I think of these sometimes and tell myself that one day I'll also have a happy married life with someone.

But my concern is, am I doing the zina of heart by thinking about intimacy with my imaginary future wife and is it a sin? Note that I don't think of any specific individual as I don't know who she'll be. It's completely in my Imagination. But yes I sometimes wish and imagine that her behavior and physical appearance might be like the girl I liked previously.

Jazakallah Khair.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No there is no such thing as zina of heart, there is zina of the eyes, the smell, the ear, the private parts, the touch. There is no zina of the heart.

But beware, do not think that you will find those bodies and fake things on porn sites in real life (keep in mind that porn is just cinematography).

Attractiveness shouldn’t be your major factor to choose with, after some time you will just get used to your wife however she is and you will start liking other things.

It is not haram to think about intimacy, it is instead makruh because it can lead you to stronger desires (which may cause you to watch porn or do the major zina which is haram).

Imagination is not haram at all (wet dreams aren’t haram). Islam is a wise religion that is here to prepare us for the day of judgment, you will get bad deeds if you do the zina but you will not get bad deeds for thinking about your future wife because it is not punished by Allah in the day of judgement.

Comment: Thanks. This is what I was looking for. I knew pornography isn't real life even when I was addicted. The girl I liked previously, it was not for her beauty. It was for her personality, her intelligence, she prayed five times daily and was serious about religion. These qualities were my main attraction point. Although I was also attracted to her physical appearance after sometimes, but I think that was due to love and desire.

Answer (score 0):

Brother do not lose hope you will leave those addctions you are not the only one struggling here you will be freed make dua and have faith in الله. There is zina of the eyes pornography that is why it is haram. Ma... is also haram.Its okay to think but not do.
And to repent for those addictions you must
Admit that it is a sin
Regret it
Apologize to الله
Promise that you won't do it again
If you fall again you repent again
It doesn't matter how many times you fall but how many you SINCERELY repent. Jazakallah for reading